# What is the best way to parse the below json structure using gson model or model class

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, json-deserialization

Is there any best way to parse the below JSON structure:

```
[{
        "0": {
            "state": {
                "type": "A",
                "stat": "ready"
            },
            "nodes": {
                "type": "B",
                "state": "ready"
            }
        },
        "1": {
            "state": {
                "type": "C",
                "state": "ready"
            },
            "nodes": {
                "type": "D",
                "state": "ready"
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "state": {
                "type": "C",
                "state": "ready"
            },
            "nodes": {
                "type": "D",
                "state": "ready"
            }
        }
    
    }]
```

I have used the below code to parse.
List<LinkedTreeMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>> result = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(restResponse.getBody(),ArrayList.class);
Is there any efficient way to parse ?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory to use **Gson** for this ? I feel like **Jackson** will be more efficient for parsing, kinda like so:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

// create instance of objectMapper:
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// define the java type you want to be parsed:
TypeReference<List<LinkedTreeMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<LinkedTreeMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>>() {};

// use objectMapper's value to parse the data:
List<LinkedTreeMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>> result = mapper.readValue(restResponse.getBody(), typeRef);
```

Now, if it's mandatory to use Gson, I'd try to improve the performance a little, for example using **JsonReader** class to parse the data incrementally, thus optimizing memory usage:

```
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import java.io.StringReader;

// creating insance of the JsonReader class and passing it to JSON as StringReader
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(restResponse.getBody()));

// using beginArray:
reader.beginArray();

// loop to read the elements in the array
while (reader.hasNext()) {
// beginObject to start reading
  reader.beginObject();
  
  // use nextName and nextString methods to read each field in the object currently:
  String name = reader.nextName();
  String value = reader.nextString();
  
  // make some changes with the name and value
  
  // finish reading the current object:
  reader.endObject();
}

// finish reading the array:
reader.endArray();
```